# Geolocation not working in IE 11

Tags: geolocation

I have tried getting the current location in other browsers and it is working fine, except for IE 11 and mobile devices. It also supports geolocation but the current location is still not coming up.

Comment: What language are you trying to get this from?  What exactly are you trying to do?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am using geolocation for getting the current location coordinates of a device and i am able to get those for all browsers except ie11. I am using web forms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @micstr for your advice.                                                                                        I have been working with asp.net web forms. I am trying to obtain the current latitude and longitude of a device using geolocation.
I have succesfully achieved that for chrome and firefox but i am unable to get the location in IE 11 and mobile devices.